# Format selection for python isn't working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed black formatter, and it formats the whole document fine (alt+shift+f).

However, when I select some text and press ctrl+k ctrl+f, it tells me that this key combination isn't a command.
Changing it to a different shortcut didn't help.

[image]

Comment: exact error message please. What does the language mode indicator at the bottom right of the screen say?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the status bar.